# How to know my Kubernetes ephimeral pod IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Hello I have a kubernetes cluster in GCP  with multiple nodes and I have cronjobs which deploy a ephimeral pod who has to connect to external service (FTP out of GCP)

In this service I have to allow IPs but I'm not sure with which IP it present my pod into this service since are cronjobs I'm to sure if these pods are exposed to the internet by default. If not, how do I should expose it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes networking is built around the notion that every pods will get an IP within the cluster, and that every pod IP is reachable from within the cluster. This IP address however will be non routable and internal to the cluster.

Which is not to say that your pod can't reach the internet. It will depend on the implementation, but chances are that the source IP will be NAT'd to that of the node on which the POD reside. If your nodes have public addresses, you should probably whitelist all of these in your service.

Comment: Then, how should I configure the cronjob to have access to internet? As they are ephimeral I cannot connect to the shell to do some connection tests.. : /

Comment: If you have a route to the Internet from within your network, you don't have anything to do (name resolution is another issue but it should work out of the box with most clusters). If you don't, you'll need to configure a proxy that is suitable for the protocol you'll be using.